# Create a Power BI custom connector for Xero API

Tags: connector, xero-api, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to create a Power BI custom connector using M Language in Visual Studio, I am stuck at how to connect to Xero cloud server and perform OAuth authentication with it, anyone can show me the sample codes would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't use M language, but have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-xero?